# I want to get the latitude and longitude of the plurality of address

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Google Geocoding API, either would not be able to send plurality of addresses in a single request?

I tried the following code.

```
GeoApiContext context = getContext();
context.setApiKey("");
context.setEnterpriseCredentials("gme-***", "***");

GeocodingApiRequest req = GeocodingApi.geocode(context, "Tokyo Japan, Osaka Japan");
req.language("ja");
GeocodingResult[] results = req.awaitIgnoreError();
for (GeocodingResult result : results) {
    System.out.println(result.geometry.location.lat);
    System.out.println(result.geometry.location.lng);
}
```

I want to reduce the request.

Comment: Try this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=user_address

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590135/how-to-get-reverse-geocode-two-coordinates-that-is-one-is-source-and-destinatio/