# How to get reverse geocode two coordinates, that is one is source and destination using Google geocoding API

Tags: reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have two set of coordinates i.e. one is source and destination. I want to geocode them but in a single shot... not by calling Geocoding API twice. Is there a way this can be achieved ? If not what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

If your intent is to find routes between latlngs and have addresses for the origin and destination of those routes, just use the Directions API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

You'll find start_address and end_address in the response. Bear in mind these are the addresses of start_location and end_location respectively, which may not be the latlngs you provided initially.

If your intent is to simply reverse geocode 2 latlngs at once, regardless of the route from one to another, there is just no way to do that in the Geocoding API: just send one request per latlng.